# can I use constraint and index in a single query to load csv to neo4j?

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I was trying to import csv to neo4j and it worked but slow.
So I am trying to use 'CONSTRAINT' to speed it up.

My following works

```
     'USING PERIODIC COMMIT \
      LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM {filepath} AS row WITH \
      row limit 1000 \
      MERGE (spot:Spot{id:row.id}) \
      .....there are more line actually ... \
     '
```

but it does not work when I add 'constraint' to the query, say syntax error.

```
     'CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (s:Spot) ASSERT s.id is UNIQUE;\
      USING PERIODIC COMMIT \
      LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM {filepath} AS row WITH \
      row limit 1000 \
      MERGE (spot:Spot{id:row.id}) \
      .....there are more line actually ... \
     '
```

I tried to run constraints first, then load csv right after. but the following says some error.

```
         var unique_str = ' CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (s:Spot) ASSERT s.id is UNIQUE \
                       CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:City) ASSERT c.id is UNIQUE \
                       CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (t:Tag) ASSERT t.id is UNIQUE; '
```

what is wrong with it?

Keep having problems, could someone point out my mistakes please.
What should I do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are trying to create a constraint for Spot twice. Remove one

Comment: @TomažBratanič removed one, still not working. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema operations, such as creating a constraint, and creating an index must be done in their own transactions, where that operation is the only statement in the transaction.

What client are you using? Using the official Javascript driver it would look something like this:

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));
var session = driver.session();
session.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (s:Spot) ASSERT s.id is UNIQUE;");
session.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:City) ASSERT c.id is UNIQUE;");
session.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (t:Tag) ASSERT t.id is UNIQUE;");
session.run("USING PERIODIC COMMIT...");
```

`session.run` will create an implicit transaction for each statement.

Comment: I was trying to use neo4j at backend with nodejs. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that if you use `periodic commit`, it has to be the first line and that is why you get a syntax error. What i would do is create a constraint separately and then run the query as you did the first time.

Comment: you mean, run constraints first, then run query next, separate them?

Comment: yes, because I am not sure that if used in same query that they would get run many times because of periodic commit

Comment: So, constraints and query for import are better to separated.  But I am having problem with constraints, can't run several of them at once, I added them above, could you point out what is wrong with them? thx